# Magento 1.9.2.2 Contact form error (unable to send request)

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter, contact-form

I'm using Magento 1.9.2.2 version, For contact form, I used this code

```
 {
  {
    block type="core/template" name="contactForm" template="contacts/form.phtml" action="/contact-us/index/post"
  }
}.
```

Contact form mail is not sending I'm getting unable to send request error. I'm using `SMTP` pro extension form email communication, The Run `self-test` is working fine and getting mail to admin, but the front end I'm not getting success message also mail not working.

please help thanks.